# Read values of objects within objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I create a key value map like following, deMapping contains data from different sources like RBSK etc.
Now I want to read all of the values in RBSK and other sources and want to run within a foreach loop like:
 deMapping.forEach(function (data)

```js
var deMapping = {
    RBSK: {'dsUID': 'tdTwLUxcQ8R', rootNodeName: 'RBSK_GIS_Indicator', orgUnitTagName: 'MCTSCode', des: [
        {
            xmlid: "Childhood_Diseases_0_6_Female",
            dataElement: "oV163sbcJ0N",
            categoryOptionCombo: "Cmzbo9LD8pJ"
        },
        {
            xmlid: "Childhood_Diseases_0_6_Male",
            dataElement: "oV163sbcJ0N",
            categoryOptionCombo: "PnAVAPG4yvb"
        },
        {
            xmlid: "Childhood_Diseases_7_18_Female",
            dataElement: "cEPledgs7rd",
            categoryOptionCombo: "Cmzbo9LD8pJ"
        },
        {
            xmlid: "Childhood_Diseases_7_18_Male",
            dataElement: "cEPledgs7rd",
            categoryOptionCombo: "PnAVAPG4yvb"
        },
        {xmlid: "Deficiencies_0_6_Female", dataElement: "gKupqkIhW4n", categoryOptionCombo: "Cmzbo9LD8pJ"},
        {xmlid: "Deficiencies_0_6_Male", dataElement: "gKupqkIhW4n", categoryOptionCombo: "PnAVAPG4yvb"},
        {xmlid: "Deficiencies_7_18_Female", dataElement: "FuEnn0bLuoT", categoryOptionCombo: "Cmzbo9LD8pJ"},
        {xmlid: "Deficiencies_7_18_Male", dataElement: "FuEnn0bLuoT", categoryOptionCombo: "PnAVAPG4yvb"},
        {
            xmlid: "Developmental_dealy_and_disability_0_6_Female",
            dataElement: "v37HBq7C72j",
            categoryOptionCombo: "Cmzbo9LD8pJ"
        },
        {
            xmlid: "Developmental_dealy_and_disability_0_6_Male",
            dataElement: "v37HBq7C72j",
            categoryOptionCombo: "PnAVAPG4yvb"
        },
        {
            xmlid: "Developmental_dealy_and_disability_7_18_Female",
            dataElement: "S1WMlAKnF8Z",
            categoryOptionCombo: "Cmzbo9LD8pJ"
        },
        {
            xmlid: "Developmental_dealy_and_disability_7_18_Male",
            dataElement: "S1WMlAKnF8Z",
            categoryOptionCombo: "PnAVAPG4yvb"
        },
        {
            xmlid: "defect_at_birth_0_6_Female",
            dataElement: "JJO3utHjb3l",
            categoryOptionCombo: "Cmzbo9LD8pJ"
        },
        {xmlid: "defect_at_birth_0_6_Male", dataElement: "JJO3utHjb3l", categoryOptionCombo: "PnAVAPG4yvb"},
        {
            xmlid: "defect_at_birth_7_18_Female",
            dataElement: "qoVmtykHboz",
            categoryOptionCombo: "Cmzbo9LD8pJ"
        },
        {xmlid: "defect_at_birth_7_18_Male", dataElement: "qoVmtykHboz", categoryOptionCombo: "PnAVAPG4yvb"}


    ]
    }


}
```

Comment: You can use the for(var key in yourObj){} loop !

Answer (score 0):

`deMapping` is an object so you can't run `forEach` on it.

Instead, go for a for `(var prop in deMapping)` [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Instructions/for...in) (and nest your loop for each object contained if needed).

```
for (var prop in deMapping) {
    var subObj = deMapping[prop];
    for (var subProp in subObj) { // subObj is what you call RBSK, we are looping on it now
         console.debug(subProp, ":", subObj[subProp]); // will output 'dsUID': 'tdTwLUxcQ8R', rootNodeName: 'RBSK_GIS_Indicator', ... at each loop
    }
}
```

With ES6, you could also use [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Instructions/for...of) method which works on objects, strings, ...

**EDIT :**
Access `des` property and iterate over its objects, then iterate over objects properties themselves.

```
for (var prop in deMapping) {
    var subObj = deMapping[prop];
    for (var subProp in subObj) { // subObj is what you call RBSK, we are looping on it now
         if (subProp === "des") {
             subObj[subProp].forEach(function(resObj) {
                 for (var prop in resObj) {
                     console.debug(prop, ":", resObj[prop]);
                 }
             });
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please explain in detail, I am new to it

Comment: Thanks @Secular It worked but there is one problem  suppose I want to read des values then how can i do that?                   Now it returns            des : [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]

Comment: des is an array, so you can call forEach on it.

Comment: @Marshmellow I've added an example to loop over res array, then loop over all objects that it contains, enumerating their key/value

Comment: Thanks again , Can you please tell me one last thing , suppose I want to read only  value of dataElement , categoryOptionCombo then how to do that, Currently it is returning the whole tag of array with keys and values but I only want to read values of array

Comment: Do (var prop in resObj) { if (prop !== "categoryOptionCombo " || prop !== "dataElement ") { continue; }
                     console.debug(prop, ":", resObj[prop]);
                 }  It will only output value for the keys you want

Comment: I have tried still it returns all the elements and values of array, I only want suppose value of dataElement  not for others